# Why is 'bob@example.com' in array(0,1,2,3,4)?

Tags: php, comparison

Why is it that 'bob@example.com' is considered to be in_array array(0,1,2,3,4)?

```
$email = 'bob@example.com';
$validValues = array(0,1,2,4);
var_dump(in_array($email, $validValues));       // bool(true)
var_dump(in_array($email, $validValues, true)); // bool(false)
```

So what is going on here?

Comment: Absurd! Weren't == & === already less confusing, that PHP thought we could do this in array as well. One got to be really dumb to choose this as default behaviour.

Comment: it seems to me that the default value for the `$strict` argument should have been true (and one could intentionally use the confusing coercion/casting)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `0 == 'bob@example.com'` (the string is converted to a number), but `0 !== 'bob@example.com'`.

The `==` and `!=` operators perform type coercion, and will convert one operand to match the type of the other.  The `===` and `!==` operators will return false if the types of the operands are not exactly the same *and* the value of the operands are equal.

The third argument to `in_array()` determines which type of equality test is used.

Comment: I just thought to try out each key. So the casting is done the opposite of how I expected ... I expected `? 'bob@example.com' == (string) 0`

Comment: @MikeGraf That is precisely why I never use `==` or `!=` in PHP anymore.  They are more confusing than they are useful.

Comment: (You'll get the correct answer in 11 minutes when I'm allowed to)

Answer (score 0):

The third attribute of `in_array` decides if the testing should be strict (`===`). In all other cases the inherent quirks of PHP's typecasting kicks in...

Comment: Choosing the answer by @cdhowie because he also explained why 'bob@email.com' == 0 .

Comment: @MikeGraf: I think his is the best explanation :) +1-ed it

Answer (score 0):

```
in_array($value, $array, $strict);
```

is the signature of the `in_array` function. `$strict`, if true, checks for `===`, if false only for `==`.

When you do `'bob@example.com' == 0` you'll have true as a result.

So when you execute your first check it thinks that `$email == 0` and returns true.